# Connecting and importing models from multiple database connections Django

Tags: django, postgresql, multiple-databases, django-queryset, nameerror

In a django app, I have two postgresql databases connected through settings.py: one is default and other is AppDb. AppDb is placed on a remote machine.

I want to query from a 'Courses' model from AppDb using 'using()' and 'Courses' model is not available in default database.

So my query goes like this:

```
courseInfo = Courses.objects.using('AppDb').filter(cuser_id = 12)
```

But I am getting NameError for 'Courses'

Can I have a solution for such queries without using routers

Comment: Make sure you have imported your model class first: `from .models import Courses`.

Comment: Is there a way to import models from an app which is on remote machine?

Comment: What is the actual problem you are trying to solve? Your question is a bit odd.

Comment: I am trying to connect to remote database which is not default database of an app and querying using it. But models are not getting recognised. I i don't know how to import them

Answer (score 0):

If you have an existing database, you still need to create an app and models for that database in order to use the ORM.

To help you create the model classes, you can use the [`inspectdb` management command](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/1.6/howto/legacy-databases/) which will try to guess the models from an existing database and create the `models.py` for you. Its not perfect, but it will save you some time.

You will still have to make sure the models have a primary key and are written in the correct order (so that foreign keys will work correctly).

Comment: Thank you for adding answer. I tried some part of it and works out that I will use cursor.connection method. As creating models and app doesn't make sense for me without having data stored in it.